# Sort a collection in grails by date

Tags: grails

I am wanting to sort a collection in grails by date I am currently doing the following:

```
def pics = Picture.findAllByChild(child, [sort: 'dateCreated', order: 'desc'])
pics.add(Post.findAllByPostedToAll(true))
```

Because I have added more items to the list i need to sort again by dateCreated descending
It doesn't look like the sort class can do this.
I have tried:

```
pics.sort(it.dateCreated)
```

But this is not allowed

Comment: What do you mean by "But this is not allowed"? What sort of error message are you getting? Etc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

the `sort` method takes a closure argument, so the correct call (with implicit parens) is

```
pics.sort { it.dateCreated }
```

Comment: In the mentioned method, is there a way to define the order? such as 'asc' or 'desc'

Comment: Is the only solution using .reverse() function following the sort?

Comment: @Visahan The closure can act as a comparator, so `{ a, b -> b.dateCreated <=> a.dateCreated }` will reverse sort.

Answer (score 2):

You can also change the default sort on the association.

In your Picture domain class add:

```
static mapping = { 
    child(sort:'dateCreated', order:'desc')
}
```

This is not supported for unidirectional one to many relationships, but works great for bidirectional ones.